# PHP - Queue incoming HTTP posts

Tags: php, queue

I am writing an integration between several application in PHP. One application is outputting a webhook style HTTP post into a .php file on my webserver which then processes and sends the data to the other systems.

Presumably each POST will be executed asynchronously, which presents a few problems:

1. The task takes time to complete, which MAY cause more threads to be
   running than the server can handle
2. There are API call limits on the services I am trying to post the
   data too. I could well exceed them with a high volume of posts.

**Is there a simple way to 'queue' HTTP requests?** (I cant reject the POST really, if I do I won't get it again).

I've considered accepting the request and saving it to a database (quicker task) AND then have a CRON task iterating through records on the database. This would work but seems messy.

Comment: if your server cannot handle a lot requests in a time phrase, its time you upgrade or dedicate a server to requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you're working on a low budget project, the most sufficient way would be the cron job IMO.

The current application sending your payload to the server could instead add a request entry to a database. The server receiving the requests can then simply run a cron job X times a day which iterates over the database entries and executes the entries as a request would.

The downside to doing this, rightfully so, is that your requests are not initiated as the action is performed. It will take time to execute the actions (depending on how frequent your cron-job runs).

> If you're not working on a low budget project, I think it is time to upgrade.

The easiest solution here is to execute payloads as they need to be executed, that meaning you send a request anytime you need a process to execute. If your server is limited to the number of requests every X hours/minutes and becomes a limitation then upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your response @KDOT. Its not a massively low budget project but I've got to be able to handle up to 15K requests per day and I've also got to work within API call limits. The CRON/database seems like a good option and will also allow me a way to filter out duplicate requests (which can happen).

Comment: You can push and pop requests through the database and then execute a script to flush the requests and do what you need to with them every X seconds/minutes/hours then :-) Jus bare in mind your script execution time doing this @BenRees

Answer (score 0):

Message queues are exactly what you need. You take the request data and send it to a message queue. The web process ends at this point and frees resources, closes the connection and so on. The messages could be processed by a pool of consumers. You can have them as many as you need to take the load. There is no need to upgrade web servers or server infrastructure if you have to them later (means you do not deal with time-critical stuff).

I'd suggest [enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev) library. You can strat from a simple queue transport like `enqueue/fs` or enqueue/dbal` and migrate to RabbitMQ or AmazonSQS on a later stages without much pain.